# group by return total three columns based on title

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL.
I am trying to write a query that will give me the total orders per product and the total money spent per product.

I have the following table:

```
order_id, title,price
1, spiderman 42 pc Lego, 18.42
2, superman 31 pc Lego, 14.37
3, spiderman 42 pc Lego, 18.42
4, spiderman 42 pc Lego, 14.23
5, superman 31 pc Lego, 14.37
```

I have this query which does half the job

```
SELECT title, COUNT(*) as total_sales from orders
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY total_sales desc;
```

I want to add to the query how much money was spent per product (I.e SUM of price per product), the price per product is not constant.

Expected output:

```
title,total_sales, price_sum
spiderman 42 pc Lego, 3, 51.07
superman 31 pc Lego, 2, 28.74
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT title, COUNT(*) as total_sales,SUM(price) as price_sum from title
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY title;
```

just add total_sales

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `view` which is basically a virtual table that runs SQL statements (even if you update the `orders` table,the view table will also be updated)

```
CREATE view orders_view AS
SELECT title, COUNT(*) as prod_sales from orders
GROUP BY title;

SELECT orders.title, prod_sales, SUM(price) from orders_view, orders
WHERE orders.title=orders_view.title
GROUP BY orders.title,prod_sales
ORDER BY prod_sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` aggregate function.

```sql
SELECT title, SUM(price) as price_sum from orders
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY title;
```

Comment: This doesn't give me the total_sales per product

Comment: just add another column in your select with your COUNT(*) and you've got it :D